# MFMailComposeViewController didFinishWithResult not being called

Tags: ios, delegates, uipopovercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, dismiss

I am writing an app with a generic form that adapts and changes based on what the user inputs into the form, they then go through and answer questions lower in the form so i have an answer check in my code to make this work, when the user clicks submit the Mail Compose View Controller loads up fine, they then either click send and the e-Mail sends but the didFinishWithResult function is not called meaning that the composer doesn't dismiss. Please see below my code:

```
@IBAction func Submit(sender: AnyObject) {

    if SelectedTalkLabel.text! == "Safe Breaking Ground - Toolbox Talk" && ASwitch.on && BSwitch.on && DSwitch.on && !(CSwitch.on)    ||    SelectedTalkLabel.text! == "Loading & Unloading Vehicles - Toolbox Talk" && ASwitch.on && BSwitch.on && CSwitch.on && !(DSwitch.on)    ||    SelectedTalkLabel.text! == "Orteco - Toolbox Talk" && ASwitch.on && CSwitch.on && !(BSwitch.on) && !(DSwitch.on) {


        let toRecipents = ["example@abc.com"]
        let emailTitle = "New ToolBox Talk Submission received!"
        let messageBody = String(format: "")

        let mc : MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self


        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
        mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
        mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)

        self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

        switch result.rawValue {

        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
            print("cancelled")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        case MFMailComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
            print("failed")
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        case MFMailComposeResultSaved.rawValue:
            print("saved")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        case MFMailComposeResultSent.rawValue:
            print("sent")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


        default:
            break

        }

        if SelectedTalkLabel.text! == "Safe Breaking Ground - Toolbox Talk" && !(ASwitch.on) || !(BSwitch.on) || !(DSwitch.on)    ||    SelectedTalkLabel.text! == "Loading & Unloading Vehicles - Toolbox Talk" && !(ASwitch.on) || !(BSwitch.on) || !(CSwitch.on)    ||    SelectedTalkLabel.text! == "Orteco - Toolbox Talk" && !(ASwitch.on) || !(CSwitch.on) {

            let WrongAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Answer!", message: "You have selected the wrong answers, please go back and try again", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let WrongDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Cancel, handler: {
                (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            })

            WrongAlert.addAction(WrongDismiss)

            self.presentViewController(WrongAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is similar to code I have used in other forms within the app that work with no dramas at all. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could try and help me out with this. Cheers.

Comment: Have you used the MFMailComposeViewController in the other places as you have mentioned? You have declared the delegate function within the scope of the IBAction function, and not the class itself.

Comment: Yeah I've used it in other ViewController files.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and was searching for a fix from past 2 days then I found a fix myself and you won't believe how minor it was.

In my case the view controller (say 'DetailsTableViewController' as per this question where your 'Submit' button is present) from where I was presenting the `MFMailComposeViewController` is already being presented from some other view controller (say 'BaseViewController').

The issue was lying in the '`modalPresentationStyle`' of 'DetailsTableViewController' while presenting it from BaseViewController.

The moment I changed it from '`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`' to '`UIModalPresentationPageSheet`' (for that matter any thing other than '`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`') issue got resolved and mail controller delegate methods started firing as usual.

Note: I was already calling the below method in 'DetailsTableViewController' (for this example) so it didn't really matter for me which '`modalPresentationStyle`' I was using.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Hope this might solve your issue as well.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tired swapping out:

```
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

with

```
controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is irrelevant. The question clearly states that `didFinishWithResult` is not being called in the first place.